Intuition for independence
Suppose that $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ are independently identically distributed real random variables. $P(X_1 < X_2 \cap X_1 < X_3) = \frac{1}{6}$ by symmetry. Thus ${X_1 < X_2}$ is not independent to ${X_1 < X_3}$ by definition. However this is a bit counter intuitive as ${X_2 > X_1}$ doesn't seem to impose any restriction on how $X_1$ is distributed, how does it affect ${X_3 > X_1}$? What is the intuition behind the fact that  ${X_1 < X_3}$ is independent to ${X_1 < X_2}$?

It's $\frac13$, not $\frac16$. The intuition is that if you know $X_1<X_2$, it means $X_1$ is more likely to be small, which makes $X_1<X_3$ more likely too.

Why is $P[X_1 < X_2 \text{ and } X_1 < X_3] = 1/6$?

If they are fair coin tosses the probability is ${1 \over 8}$.
